# How to do a box shadow in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, css

I'm using this for firefox and web kit browsers:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #888;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px #888;
```

for IE, I found 2 filters from this article:

http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-with-css-for-all-web-browsers/

```
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#888')";
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
```

but these 2 filters are for the example on that article, not the box shadow effect I'm looking to acheive. I tried to alter it but I'm not familiar with IE filters. Can anyone please alter these 2 filters to work with the drop shadow I effect I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't bother setting up those filters since  they won't behave exactly the same as box-shadow.

For my projects I use [css3PIE](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#box-shadow) which adds css3 features to IE browsers who don't support them. I find this solution for box-shadow to be far more consistent. And you can use normal css3 syntax - all you need to do is load the library.

Comment: +1 for css3pie. Best tool for the job. The only other viable option is just to leave IE users without the shadow.

Comment: I love you dude, this thing is awesome and super easy to implement!

Comment: Just take care with it - use 1-2 maybe 3 of features it offers at same time - else it can still get buggy. position:relative often fixes the problems. they also have a great f.a.q.